# No job alerts via email

Tags: bug, status-completed, email, stack-overflow-jobs

I no longer receive daily job alerts (the last I successfully received was in late February).

It's a Gmail account. I'm under quota. I've checked both the Spam and Trash folders.

One possible cause: for some unknown period of time, my email forwarding was broken. So, perhaps there is logic in the email alert code that stops sending email to accounts that return bounced mail?

At any rate, I'd be grateful if someone were to reset this flag, if that is indeed the problem.

Comment: I got an alert yesterday. For a job in India that I am obviously not interested in. So the system is at least partially working.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for this piece of data. I looked into the possibility that I'd created a relevant filter, or had configured forwarding within the account itself. No such luck.

Comment: @CodyGray Well, I'm not sure what was done on your end, but email alerts resumed yesterday. Thanks.

Comment: Not my end. I don't work for Stack Exchange. I'm just a community-elected moderator. But it looks like one of the staff members (Max) has just looked into this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> perhaps there is logic in the email alert code that stops sending email to accounts that return bounced mail?

That's exactly what happened. That code actually isn't part of our own email alerting, it's the standard behavior of our email sending provider. Once an email address bounces, it gets filtered out going forward.

We're in the process of switching to a different provider, which means your email address basically got another chance when we cut over the job alert email. Since it didn't bounce this time, you got unblocked.